# Profile 32-bit app on 64-bit system using INTEL PIN

Tags: c, profiling, cross-compiling, intel-pin

I compiled a C program using -*m32 gcc* option . I want to profile this program using a Pin tool . My kernel is 64 bit.

I have tried :-

1) `pin -t64 <64-bit toolname> -t <32-bit toolname> -- <application>`

2) `pin -t <32-bit toolname> -- <application>`

3) `pin -t <64-bit toolname> -- <application>`

I have the same .cpp tool file for both the tools compiled differently for 32 bit and 64 bit architectures.

Case 3 invoked an error 'unable to load .. Check the architecture type' .
Cases 1 and 2 , the command was successful but produced some unexpected output , for ex names of images written into a file is empty in this case but contains proper results when executed with a 64-bit application . Which is the correct way to set up the pin tool for this case?

Comment: You're invoking pin in the correct way in cases 2 and 1 (case 1 is for complex process tree flows). I suspect the issue is not Pin itself but something in the Pintool. Can you share a minimal reproducer of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

well i found a workaround to compile the 32bit library of pin ( i mean instcount0 ) in 64bit arch.

i did modify the config file related to building the library.

i have pin located in /opt/ so , i edited

```
/opt/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/source/tools/Config
```

at line 38

```html
# Define the architecture of the target
# ; TARGET ?= $(HOST_ARCH)
TARGET = ia32
ifeq ($(TARGET),ia32)
    BITS := 32
else
    BITS := 64
endif
```

i just changed the target to ia32. works just fine after build .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few caveats to know when starting a program under pin control:

1) The pintool **must be compiled in the same architecture** than the instrumented program (so, if your program is 32-bit, your pin tool must be 32-bit).

2) Ensure your system is setup to execute 32-bit programs on a 64-bit OS (some linux systems still need `ia32-libs` and / or need to be prepared for executing 32-bit programs (e.g. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`)

3) Ensure you have [all required libraries for PIN](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#LIBRARIES)

4) Use [pin.sh](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#PIN_LAUNCHER)

Your command should be:

- `pin -t pintool.so -- <program> <program-options>`

If you still have problems it is probably a problem with your pintool code rather than pin itself.

Did you tried one of the simple example (like `inscount`) on your program ?

Comment: I have taken care of all the four cases you have mentioned ,  even the given inscount.so doesn't give any output for the 32-bit executable. What can be the error then? As given , I have compiled it separately for 32-bit architecture. But then for my tool  , I collect information about branches and functions which come properly but file that contains the names of images is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your PIN binary.

```
file PIN_DIR/pin
```

I downloaded PIN kit from this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-binary-instrumentation-tool-downloads). My PIN binary is 32-bit. If yours is 64-bit version, you can modify codes that check system architecture in pin.sh, and run

```
PIN_DIR/pin.sh
```

That should give you a 32-bit version PIN binary.